# Named query not visible in the explorer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have created a business network and exported as .bna. I deployed that .bna and created a rest-server using composer-rest-server.

But I am unable to find the named queries, which I defined .qry file in the explorer dashboard.

Could you tell me, what could be an issue which is not reflecting the query REST board. I can see another query. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to see the named query after changing the bna name and redeploying it.  I am not sure, was there any issue with cache, which might be pointing it older bna name.

Comment: shouldn't be a cache issue. Was it possible you didn't use the right BNA file to deploy originally? And if a network was previously deployed - you would use `composer network update` to update it - and then run composer-rest-server again to regenerate the REST schema, endpoints etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command while creating the archive file:

```
composer archive create --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a airlinev8.bna
```

`--sourceName .`  means current folder.